# How to make custom city picker in android

Tags: android

Hi i want to make a custom city picker . The name of cities will come from api .
I want to show them as in the picture . The middle city will be picked when the search button is clicked . But i cant think of way to do it .
Any Help?

[image: The image shows the details]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As weird as it may sound, you can use a numberpicker to display and select the countries:

```
NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(this);
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(countries.length()-1);
picker.setDisplayedValues(countries);
```

The countries variable is an array of strings.